# Sorting which string is bigger in java , Array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort the strings in the array, by alphabetizing them, but I get an error with argument types.

```
public class BubbleSort {
 public static String[] sortStringArray(String[] stringArray) {
     int s = stringArray.length;
     String temp;

        for (int i = 0 ; i < s; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (s - i); j++) {
                    String a1 = stringArray[j - 1];
                    String b1 = stringArray[j];
                    int result = a1.compareTo(b1);
                if (result > stringArray[j]) {
                    temp = stringArray[j - 1];
                    stringArray[j - 1] = stringArray[j];
                    stringArray[j] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
    return stringArray;
 }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) int, String

Comment: `result > stringArray[j]` compares an `int` to a `String`, which is not possible.

Comment: You could btw simply use [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) to solve this probolem.

Comment: Could you show me how, im not familiar with this method?

Comment: @J.Rod sorry, the link in my comment is wrong. Here is the right one [`Arrays.sort(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-). Documentation should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're calling [`compareTo(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) on `String`s, you need to check then if the result is bigger than zero:

```
if (0 < result) { // i.e. a1 is smaller than b1
    //swap values as usual
}
```

Comment: Small remark: you speak about checking if `result < 0`, but you actually check `0 < result`, which is `resutl > 0`. Your porgram logic is correct, but the formulation is confusing.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks, updated the explanation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a String array by natural ordering you can use `Arrays.stream`

eg:

```
String[] s = {"b", "c", "a", "aaa", "abc"};
s = Arrays.stream(s).sorted().toArray(String[]::new);
```

gives `s= [a, aaa, abc, b, c]`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (result > stringArray[j])
```

`result` is an integer, `stringarray[j]` is a string.

You can't compare with integer like that, if your string is an integer like stinrgArray[j] value is "11" and you want to compare it you need to parse it first to integer:

```
if(result > Integer.parseInt(stringArray[j]))
```

Comment: This **might** work, if the `String`s in the `array` are parseable to Integer. However, this isn't what bubble sort is about.

Comment: The OP asked question "but I get an error with argument types." so thats the answer to his question, any other answer i believe would not be necessary, for people to learn they need to try themselves, what i see people doing here that post their problem in the first stage of a problem and they get the solution for the whole problem, u need to fix their specific problem and let them try the rest by themselves

Comment: Then why not answer `result > 3`?  That's okay too as types are concened. The `result` is already the result of a comparison. So, if we want to solve OPs problem, then we show him how to interpret this value.